# open and edit multiple .csv files in c#

Tags: c#

My ideal is : open some .csv files (5 or 6 or more) and add 2 new columns to all opened files and finally save it. Here is my code

```
OpenFileDialog fopen = new OpenFileDialog();
fopen.Multiselect = true;                      
fopen.Filter = "(All type)|*.*";
fopen.ShowDialog();
if (fopen.FileName != null)
{
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
    Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fopen.FileName);
    Excel.Worksheet sheet = wb.Sheets[1];
    Excel.Range range = sheet.UsedRange;

    int column = range.Columns.Count;
    int row = range.Rows.Count;

    textBox1.Text = fopen.FileName;

    //textBox2.Text = row.ToString();
    //textBox3.Text = column.ToString();

    range.Cells.set_Item(1, column + 1, "Mo_stMoC");
    range.Cells.set_Item(1, column + 2, "Mo_stMoCCpl");

    for (int i = 2; i <= row; i++)
    {
        range.Cells.set_Item(i, column + 1, "0");
        range.Cells.set_Item(i, column + 2, "0");
    }
    wb.Save();
    wb.Close();  
    app.Workbooks.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```

The problem is, when I open the files and it just adding 2 columns in the first .csv file.
I'm new to C#, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you didnt loop ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are opening [multiple files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples), so loop through  fopen.FileNames instead of just using fopen.FileName

```
 foreach (String file in fopen.FileNames) 
{
  //do your thing
  //edit
}
```

Additionally it is better to filter only csv files instead of all.

```
 fopen.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv";
```